# Filter past events with condition

Tags: solidity, web3js

Is it possible to filter past events with a boolean condition? For example I have the following event:

```
event ExampleEvent(uint256 exampleNumber);
```

In my `js` code I can filter these events with the `==` operator as follows:

```
const pastEvents = await exampleContract.getPastEvents("ExampleEvent", { filter: {exampleNumber: 10}, fromBlock: 1 });
```

Is it possible to filter with different operators? eg like this: `exampleNumber>10`